# Salutations or greetings for the various Jewish holidays

Tags: calendar

Is it right to, and is there a particular salutation for most of the major holidays in the Jewish calendar?
I have a couple of new friends who celebrate their Jewish faith, I was wondering if there was a generic salutation or specific salutations for the various holidays?
Specifically thinking about Shavuot, but was wondering in general too.
https://www.hebcal.com/holidays/2018

Comment: I hope this is an ok place to ask this kind of question :)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Gabriel. It is a perfectly fine question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One traditional greeting for Jewish holidays is Chag sameach, meaning "a joyous holiday".**

Some of the holidays have specific variations of the greeting, or specific greetings, e.g., taking your list in order

- **Pesach**: Chag kasher vesameach (meaning a kosher and joyous holiday, a reference to the fact Jews don't eat leavened products on Pesach)
- **Tisha b'Av**: due to the sad nature of the day, Jews do not greet each other on that day
- **Rosh Hashana**: Shana tova (a good year)
- **Yom Kippur**: Chatima tova (a good signature - as we hope to be inscribed in the book of the living for the year to come)

**But you cannot go wrong with Chag sameach !** (except on Tisha b’Av as noted above)